# How to pass parameters for a sub screen with react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a screen tab contains 2 components

I want to pass my param id

```
    this.props.navigation.navigate("TabsScreen2", {id: idFilm})
```

TabsScreen2 is my screen bottomtab

My bottomTab

```
const MainStack = createStackNavigator();
const MainStackScreen = () => (
  <MainStack.Navigator>
    <MainStack.Screen
      name="TabsScreen2"
      component={TabsScreenFilmDetail}
      options={{ title: "FilmDetail Screen title" }}>
        
    </MainStack.Screen>
  </MainStack.Navigator>
);

        const TabsFilmDetail = createBottomTabNavigator();
    const TabsScreenFilmDetail = (e) =>  {
      console.log('e ', e.route.params )
      return (
        <TabsFilmDetail.Navigator>
          <TabsFilmDetail.Screen name="FilmDetail" params={e} component={FilmDetailStackScreenNav} />
          <TabsFilmDetail.Screen name="FavoriteList" component={FavoriteListStackScreenNav} />
        </TabsFilmDetail.Navigator>
      );
    }
```

in my log , i have my id is ok
but how to pass my param to my <TabsFilmDetail.Screen name="FilmDetail">
I try params parameter or other property and it's didn't work.
It exist a solution to pass a simple param ?
thanks for help

Comment: You can use pass the params as initialParams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the right keyword you are looking for is initialParams

Like this in one of my codes

[image]

So I think in case of your code, you need to change from this

```
<TabsFilmDetail.Screen name="FilmDetail" params={e} component={FilmDetailStackScreenNav} />
```

to this

```
<TabsFilmDetail.Screen name="FilmDetail" initialParams={e} component={FilmDetailStackScreenNav} />
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
            <TabsFilmDetail.Screen name="FilmDetail">
                {(props) => <FilmDetailStackScreenNav {...props} e={e.route.params} />}
            </Tab.Screen>
```

Comment: If i do your solution , i have an error Uncaught Error: Got both 'component' and 'children' props for the screen 'FilmDetail'. You must pass only one of them.     The solution with  <FilmDetailStackScreen.Screen name="FilmDetail" initialParams={e.route.params} component={FilmDetail} /> ( initialParams ) works very fine.   Thank for your help